# Extension update - Technical submission fails

Tags: extensions, magento2.3, marketplace

Magento 2.3 got `CsrfAwareActionInterface`, which needs to be implemented in order to be able to handle webhooks properly.

I got the following

```php
$part = interface_exists('Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface') ? 'new' : 'old';
include_once sprintf('a/b/c/d+%s.php', $part);
```

In practice, this works, `CsrfAwareActionInterface` won't exist in Magento <2.3, but Magento's code sniffer won't agree.

It tests the code with PHP 7.1 and is successful, then it tries PHP 5.6 which has no return types, resulting in 
`PHP syntax error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'`, telling me to fix the errors and resubmit.

Implementing the interface without compatible return types won't work.

Releasing 2 different versions (2.3 & <2.3) and supporting them wouldn't be wise, given that `CsrfAwareActionInterface` would be the sole difference between them.

Is the result of that test (code sniffer) breaking? Can an extension be approved despite that test failing?

Comment: Which codesniff ruleset?

Comment: MEQP2.PHP.Syntax.PHPSyntax. It's not about the Code Sniffer itself, but how it's configured @ Magento marketplace level, it seems to be an acknowledged bug - https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/issues/104

Answer (score 0):

They are moving to https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Code-Sniff-Test-Updates-for-the-Extension-Quality-Program/ba-p/134574, which will fix the issue, or so they say.

Comment: Hasn't fixed anything, it's still just a code sniffer and not an environment emulation.